How to make a negative control
In USP <61> (United States Pharmacopeia), it mentions that we would need a negative control when we are testing products for any microbial growth. It doesn't necessarily explain how to make negative control. So how would I make a negative control? Is it just from any of the diluent buffers such as Phosphate Buffered Saline or is it just simply water? or something else?

This is spelled out under the section of USP<61> on growth promotion and system suitability.

To verify testing conditions, a negative control is performed using the chosen diluent in place the teste preparation There must be no growth of microorganisms. A negative control is also performed when testing the products as described under Testing of Products. A failed negative control requires an investigation

During product testing the purpose of the negative control is to demonstrate what negative/no growth test result looks like, but if done right it can also help demonstrate that any growth observed in your testing actually came from the test article, rather than being introduced during the testing procedure by some non-sterile equipment or reagent. This just entails treating your negative control as if it were an actual test article by preparing them side-by-side follow all of the same procedures.
During system suitability testing, I think you want two negative controls. One that is just the diluent and one that is the diluent with the product in it. Or whatever setup you're using to demonstrate that your protocol can detect the specified test organisms in the presence of your product.

It depends entirely on what and how you are testing.
In general it is a control that is used to show what no growth looks like under your system. Often this means adding a known sterile version of your drug/compound to medium and incubating in some manner. Adding the sterile version accounts for substances that might change a characteristic such as absorbance or turbidity of the medium you are using for your testing.
It could also be that you just retain a vial/plate of medium without anything added to it.

ok cool that is very helpful. Thank you very much!
